# If a field I'm accessing is part of a compound index do I still get the benefits of that index just referencing one of the fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, query-performance

In MySQL I have a compound index on 2 fields (a,b). If I'm accessing only field a as part of a query do I still get the benefits of the index?

Thanks

Comment: When you use `WHERE a = 'value'` Yes...When you use `WHERE b = 'value'` No.. but you can still use the index when you need to filter on b  for example if a and b are (var)char columns `WHERE a > 'a' AND b = 'value'`

Comment: Cookbook:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of a telephone book. It's basically a sorted index on last_name, first_name.

Does the fact that the telephone book is sorted in that way help you to look up people even if you search only by last name?

Yes, it does.